# Checking for object data

Tags: javascript, html

How do i successfully check if a html object's data is equal to that of a variable on button click? I've tried this but it just seems to be executing the code whether the statement is correct or not.

```
var FL1 = document.getElementById("FL1Object").data
var Data = 'FL1.png'

document.getElementById("FLLeftBtn").onclick = function() 
{FLLeftBtnClicked()};

function FLLeftBtnClicked() {
    if (FL1 = Data) {
        alert("Test Successful");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but there's no need to write an entirely new function that just calls `FLLeftBtnClicked()`. Just assign `FLLeftBtnClicked` directly to `onclick`.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong operator in **if condition**

```
var FL1 = document.getElementById("FL1Object").data
var Data = 'FL1.png'

document.getElementById("FLLeftBtn").onclick = function() 
{FLLeftBtnClicked()};

function FLLeftBtnClicked() {
    if (FL1 == Data) { //use == to compare items
        alert("Test Successful");
    }
}
```

Comment: Preferable to use === to avoid coercion?

Comment: I assumed that thing, my bad! changed! @brk

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [data_attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) the right way to get it's value is by using `getAttribute` or `document.getElementById('elementId').dataset.someKey`

```js
var FL1 = document.getElementById("FL1Object").getAttribute('data-img')

var Data = 'FL1.png'

document.getElementById("FLLeftBtn").onclick = function() {
  FLLeftBtnClicked()
};

function FLLeftBtnClicked() {
  if (FL1 === Data) {
    alert("Test Successful");
  }
}
```

```html
<object id="FL1Object" data-img="FL1.png">
<button id = "FLLeftBtn">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is a syntax error. Do `if (FL1 == Data)` instead of `if (FL1 = Data)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
if (FL1 = Data)
```

Make it like this:

```
if (FL1 === Data)
```

The reason it is executing the code everytime is that '=' is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator and it returns value of `Data` variable and passes it in the condition which is converted by JavaScript to **true**. Hence, the condition is always true.

Read [this](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/01/using_the_assig.html) post for more details.